How to create deeplink for teams custom app if app is running under M365 and Office context
We have developed one custom app for Microsoft Teams that uses an external provider for authentication.
The authentication mechanism has been implemented as per the following documentation:
learn.microsoft.com: Use external OAuth providers
As per the above documentation, the use of deeplink has been suggested for redirecting the user to the app if it is not a web application.
return res.redirect(`msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/auth-callback?authId=${state.authId}&result=${req.query.code}`)
The above implementation has been tested by the Microsoft Partner Center validation team, and it is working fine. If we are trying to use the custom app inside the Desktop Teams Client and Web Teams Client.
Problem:
If we try to use the custom app inside the M365 or Office context, then the user is redirected to the Desktop Teams Client (custom app) upon successful authentication.
The deeplink's reference to the msteams://teams.microsoft.com domain is the cause of this.
Due to the above issue, the Microsoft Partner Center team is not approving our custom app.
Any help on this would be appreciated.
I was looking for some documentation which we can use for our reference but did not find anything.

We checked this internally and we have the following suggestion - Rather than hardcoding the "msteams://teams.microsoft.com" redirect URL; the app developer should leverage the hostRedirectUrl as covered in step 6 here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-oauth-provider#add-authentication-to-external-browsers - https://i.sstatic.net/3GxJcDil.png

@Meghana-MSFT Thanks for helping us with this issue. I can see in the above link the hostRedirectUrl is being passed from step 1. But I am not sure how to get that at step 1. Like for teams, I know it is msteams://teams.microsoft.com. But what the hostRedirect value will be for M365 and Office.

The doc says that for Teams you can use that hard coded deeplink. The doc also says that for other hosts you can redirect to clientRedirectURL which is provided by the hubSDK and a custom url for each specific hub.

@Meghana-MSFT We don't have much experience on working on Teams App platform. Also there is no mentioning of hubSDK in the docs. Even in the sample app (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/b29d9cc9e7fd775dcd39af5ae7ee34deefc8a3c3/samples/tab-external-auth), there is no reference of that scenario. It would be very helpful if you can share some link for the reference.

You'll want to use the hostRedirectURL you can get from the URL placeholders when you launch the auth flow. As shown in the linked doc:
authentication.authenticate({
      url: `${window.location.origin}/auth-start?oauthRedirectMethod={oauthRedirectMethod}&authId={authId}&hostRedirectUrl={hostRedirectUrl}&googleId=${googleId}`,
      isExternal: true
    })

The deeplink value you're looking for is {hostRedirectUrl}; this is a deeplink back to the host that launched the auth flow. Then, all you need to do is replace the {result} placeholder in that URL and redirect. From step 6:
if (state.oauthRedirectMethod === 'deeplink') {
   const clientRedirectUrl: string = state.hostRedirectUrl.replace('{result}', req.query.code)
   return res.redirect(clientRedirectUrl)
}

